# How to have a custom setter with a named argument and default

Tags: kotlin

I have a Kotlin class with named arguments and defaults for non-specified arguments.  I am trying to figure out how to create a custom setter for one argument and just can't seem to figure out what I'm doing wrong - although it's probably simple.  Here is a simplified version of the class:

```
class ItemObject(var itemNumber: String = "",
             var itemQty: Int = 0)
```

I can use the properties of this class without issues itemObject.itemQty = itemObject.itemQty + 1 (accessing both the getter and setter).

However, I'd like to make a custom setter to prevent the itemQty from going below zero.  So I've tried many variations on the following theme:

```
class ItemObject(var itemNumber: String = "",
             itemQty: Int = 0) {

var itemQty: Int = 0
    set(value: Int) =
        if (value >= 0) {
            itemQty = value // Don't want to go negative
        } else {
        }
```

}

This compiles without issue, but seems to keep defaulting itemQty to zero (or something like this - I haven't tracked it down).

Can anyone point me in the correct direction?  I'd certainly appreciate it - this is my first Kotlin project and could use a bit of help. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you initualize the real field to 0 and ignore the passed value ... Instead,  initialize the property with the passed constructor parameter:

```
  class Item(_itemQty: Int = 0) {
     var itemQty: Int = Math.max(0, _itemQty)
        set(v) { field = Math.max(0, v) }
  }
```

(I used two different Identifiers to seperate the parameter and the property, as mentioned in the comments you can also use the same name for the property and the parameter [but be careful, that could add confusion]).

You should also set the [*backing field*](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/properties.html#backing-fields), not the setter itself which will end in endless recursion.

If the setter is rather complicated and also needs to be applied to the initial value, then you could initialize the property, and execute the setter afterwards with the parameter:

```
  class Item(_itemQty: Int = 0) {
     var itemQty: Int = 0
        set(v) { field = Math.max(0, v) }

     init { itemQty = _itemQty }
  }
```

---

As an opinion-based side note, `item.itemQty` is not really descriptive, `item.quantity` would be way more readable.

Comment: @dyukha Okay, can you verify that (I'm afk at the moment), but even if it would I would avoid the shadowing.

Comment: Yeah, it works (can't insert the link). Anti-shadowing argument is valid.

Comment: I'm actually more interested in how one can avoid `Math.max(0, ...)` duplication. I guess it can be done on getter side, but can it be done during setting?

Comment: @dyukha `init { itemQty = _itemQty }`

Comment: Thanks!  When I used the init I got this to work: `class ItemObject(var itemNumber: String = "",
             _itemQty: Int = 0) {

    var qtyOrdered: Int = 0
        get() = field
        set(value: Int) =
            if (value >= 0) {
                field = value // Don't want to go negative
            } else {}

    init { qtyOrdered = _qtyOrdered }`

Answer (score 3):

This is what `vetoable` is for:

```
var quantity: Int by Delegates.vetoable(0) { _, _, new ->
    new >= 0
}
```

Return `true` to accept the value, return `false` to reject it.

Comment: Did you mean to use the variable "quantity"?  If so, there doesn't appear to be any connection to my property itemQty.  And if I change this code to use "qtyOrdered" instead of "quantity", then I get "Conflicting declarations: public final var qtyOrdered: Int, public final var qtyOrdered: Int".   How am I using this wrong?

Answer (score 0):

There are different ways of preventing value going below zero.
One is unsigned types. Experimental at the moment. `UInt` in your case

```
class ItemObject(var itemNumber: String = "",
                 var itemQty: UInt = 0u
)
```

If you don't care about value overflow - it might be an option

Another way is Property Delegation

```
class ItemObject(var itemNumber: String = "", itemQty: Int = 0) {
    var itemQty: Int by PositiveDelegate(itemQty)
}

class PositiveDelegate(private var prop: Int) {
    operator fun getValue(thisRef: Any?, property: KProperty<*>): Int = prop

    operator fun setValue(thisRef: Any?, property: KProperty<*>, value: Int) {
        if (value >= 0) prop = value
    }
}
```

Third one with custom setters is described in other answers.